# API with pagination returns the data as array of objects but on the client I am seeing as list of maps?

Tags: pagination, client

I have an API that returns paginated data which accepts a page size of 500 to the max.
I am getting the information like below on client side, even though in Postman the data returned in the format of array of objects.

[image]

[image]